# Javascript - negative decimal input range with non-linear scale

Tags: javascript, slider, logarithm, exponential

I have an input range slider that ranges from -1000 to 1000.

```
<input type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" value="0" />
```

I want the steps to be non-linear (either log or exp) with more precision in the lower range.

So for e.g.

-1000

-999.5

-998

-996

...

0

100

300

600

1000

Doesn't exactly need to be as shown above, but I just want the steps to be closer together in the lower range and further apart in the higher range. Looking for some jQuery/JS code to help me accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with above method:

html part:

```html
<input id='digits' type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" value="0" step="100" />
```

js part:

```js
$("#digits").on("input change", function() {
       var is_negative = this.step < 0;
       this.step = (is_negative)? (Math.abs(this.step) / 1.025).toFixed(0) : Math.pow(Math.abs(this.step), 1.025).toFixed(0);
   });
```

This is not the ONE right decision, it is just the Right Direction for your case

Answer (score 0):

You can not set `step` as function directly. But you can output it to some div. For example:

```
<input id="range" name="range" type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" value="-1000" />
<output id="rangeOutput" for="range" name="level">-1000</output>
```

And on `onInput` event `step` is calculated by appropriate function, in my example - quadratic function:

```
var stepFunction = function(step, min, max){
    var range = max - min,
        coeff = Math.pow((step - min)/range, 2),
        newStep = min + coeff*range;
    return newStep;
}

$('#range').on('input', function(e){
    var target = e.target,
        step = parseInt(target.value),
        min = parseInt(target.min),
        max = parseInt(target.max);          
    $('#rangeOutput').val(stepFunction(step, min, max));
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqtv4q5L/2/)